# How can I fix the scale animation on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How can I prevent the image from getting cut when I use the scale animation on it?

Before I apply the animation it looks like this:

[image]

After the effect it looks like this:

[image: Problem]

The line that does the effect looks like this:

```
self.conditionImageView.addSymbolEffect(.scale)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.clipsToBounds = false` on your image view.

If your image view is in Storyboard, select the image view and **un-check** `Clips to Bounds` in the Attributes panel.